# Importing a node from an existing XML file add extra blank lines

Tags: java, dom

I have an XML file similar to this

```
<root>
  <child name=foo>
    <grandchild/>
  </child>
    <grandchild/>
  <child name=bar>
  </child>
</root>
```

I have a Java function that looks up a node in this XML and appends it to a new XML file

```
public void lookup(String attribValue) {
  NodeList nl = null;
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  Document sourceDoc = null;
  try {
    sourceDoc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("MyXML.xml"));
    XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//child[@name='" + attribValue + "']");
    nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(sourceDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET); 
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }

  Node node = nl.items(0);
  if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(doc.importNode(node, true));
  } else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Node is not an element");
  }
}
```

In the code above, `doc` is global variable that represents the target XML. The issue, albeit minor, is that when the target XML is saved, there are added extra blank lines similar to the example below:

```
<target>
  <child='foo'>

    <grandchild/>

  </child>
</target>
```

If there are more grandchild nodes, each one will be separated by an extra blank line. Obviously, when I create target XML, I call a function that "pretty prints" the document. The code is shown below:

```
private void writeXML(OutputStream output) {
  TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
  tranformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD , "xml");
  tranformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT , "yes");
  tranformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING , "UTF-8");
  tranformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION , "no");
  DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc); // same global variable

  StreamResult result = new StreamResult(output);
  transformer.transform(source, result);
}
```

I tried calling `normalize()` and `normalizeDocument()` on the Document, and `normalize()` on the root node and the node being imported to no avail. Based on the method documentation, I expected as much, but I tried it anyway. This is not a huge deal, but it bothered me enough to post this question. I would like for the extra blank lines to be removed.